# Import Error:No module named app.management.commands

Tags: python, django, python-import

when I run the command to import my python file, i am getting import error saying no modue named app.management.commands.

```
>>> from app.management.commands import scripty
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named app.management.commands
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: How are you expecting this statement to be loaded? From your existing file structure? What is the context?

Comment: Please, describe structure of your project

Answer (score -1):

Is `app.management.commands` in your sys path?

Looks like you have to import it using `<project_name>.app.management.commands`.

Comment: Can you please brief that. I am totally new to django